# jQuery inputmask no limit on number of characters

Tags: jquery-inputmask

I'm using the jQuery inputmask plugin for masking a text field (https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask).  I can't figure out the syntax for masking an **unlimited** number of alphanumeric characters.  This seems like it should be simple I just can't seem to find the answer in in the documentation or another stackoverflow question.  So far this works:

```
$('.inputmask_alphanumeric').inputmask({ mask: "[*]{100}", greedy: false });
```

{100} is a generous number for now, but I want this to be a generic class rule for any long text input in the future.  I tried {*} and {+} but they didn't seem to work.  Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- `[]` optional
- `()` group
- `{}` range

`[*]{100}` == Optional char `*` must be entered `100` times

You need `*{0,}` to create a `min:0` and `max:infinite` mask

Or `{1,}` to create a `min:1` and `max:infinite`

and so on :)

Comment: I've been reading documentation of this jquery library regex, and this answer is just too clear and 100% understandable, why people make it so complicated... This answer made my day...!